# Conflict with dependency findbugs when importing Google Cloud PubSub in Android gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a bare empty Android project, I am following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) for PubSub java client.
So basically I am only adding:

`compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-pubsub', version: '0.11.0-alpha'`

to my gradle (the complete file is [here](https://gist.github.com/dariosalviwork/f03e3b58b54f597ba2ccbea7a21c0afa))

The error I get is:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (3.0.0) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

There are also 2 warnings:

> Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20151123 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>
> Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

I think this is related to #1319 but I can't make those suggested solutions work out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that excluding those replicated dependencies may fix it:

so, instead of

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-pubsub', version: '0.11.0-alpha'
```

this would produce no errors nor warnings:

```
compile ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:0.11.0-alpha') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group: 'org.json'
}
```